# How to add this vim feature/key binding

Tags: sublimetext2

How do I add "delete to mark" to sublime text's key binding? The feature I'm looking for is as follows: set mark ( ma ), move a few lines down ( jjj ), delete to mark ( d'a )

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This feature is supported in the [`Vintageous`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Vintageous) plugin, which is currently only available for Sublime Text 3.

However, I would strongly urge you to [upgrade](http://sublimetext.com/3), as ST3 contains many new features over ST2, not least of which is improved stability and a fully thread-safe API, which means that there's a much lower chance of a misbehaving plugin taking down the whole program. If you've registered ST2, you are eligible to use the ST3 [dev builds](http://sublimetext.com/3dev) if you wish, otherwise you can use the latest public beta version. There are more and more plugins that are switching to just supporting ST3 (the API is now Python 3.3.3 instead of 2.6.5 for ST2), and many more support both versions. Porting is generally trivial for most plugins, so unless something has been completely abandoned the author may make a port (or you can if you know Python).